# JsonReaderException when deserializing object

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I'm trying to understand serialization/deserialization of JSON with C# so wrote the following class to help.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Size
    {
        public double ArmLength { get; set; }
        public HandPosition HandPosition { get; set; }
    }

    class HandPosition
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public double Z { get; set; }
    }
    class Dictionary
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Size size = new Size();
            size.ArmLength = 2.13;
            size.HandPosition = new HandPosition
            {
                X = 2.13,
                Y = 2.14,
                Z = 2.15
            };

            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(size, Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine("Output: " + output);

            var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(output);
            Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse(values["HandPosition"]["X"]));
            Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse(values["ArmLength"]));



            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the following exception at `var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(output);`:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'HandPosition', line 3, position 19.'

What have I done wrong here and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Because ``HandPosition`` is an object. Have you try ``Dictionary<string, object>``?

Answer (score 0):

You have overcomplicated it. To deserialize a object all you need to do is call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Size>(output)` where `Size` is the type you are deserializing too.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Size size = new Size();
    size.ArmLength = 2.13;
    size.HandPosition = new HandPosition
    {
        X = 2.13,
        Y = 2.14,
        Z = 2.15
    };

    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(size, Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine("Output: " + output);

    var deserializeSize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Size>(output);
    Console.WriteLine($"deserializeSize.Handposition.X = {deserializeSize.HandPosition.X}");
    Console.WriteLine($"deserializeSize.ArmLength = {deserializeSize.ArmLength}");

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
    Console.Read();
}
```

As a word of warning I would discourage the use of .NET built in classes as custom class names as it can become confusing when there are multiple class with the same name. `Dictionary` and `Size` are problematic in your case.